# graphical user interface app for sqlite database showing

Tags: android, sqlite

is There any app for showing sqlite databases and table in gui? like phpmyadmin for sql?
i want an app for android.
any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popular apps on GooglePlay to browse SQLite Databases :

1. **[SQLite Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager&hl=en)**
2. **[SQLite Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kokufu.android.apps.sqliteviewer.free&hl=en)**

You can find many more [here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sqlite&c=apps).